# viewstate enable in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I have a doubt in viewstate, if viewstate enable="false" then the viewstate not maintain the state of the control. Is there any reference or any good article. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable viewState for one control or for the complete page.
It's better using viewState only for forms controls that need to keep their values through Postbacks. Especially if you need an high performance web.

Answer (score 0):

This MSDN article explains viewstate well.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx